# Do you need to use Entity Framework to create a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

Is there a way of creating WCF Service without using Enitity Framework?

Comment: the default Visual Studio template does not use Entity framework at all. so you may choose any DB access logic you like.

Comment: Why do you think WCF has a dependency on Entity Framework?

Comment: off course there is, WCF and EF are different technologies, wcf is a data-exhange framework, EF is an ORM framework

Comment: Shortest possible answer: **no**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. (short answer for the title "Do you need to use Entity Framework to create a WCF Service")

to explain simply :
WCF is for communication, data exchange.
EF is for relational mapping, like database exchange.

that's différent and there is no dependendy.